# Linear independence in an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume I am given an $\mathbb{R}$ v.sp. $F$ with an inner product $(-,-)$, $v_1,...,v_m\in F$ such that $(v_i,v_j)\leq 0$ for $i\neq j$ and assume there is an $x\in F$ such that $(v_i,x)>0$ for all $i$.

Is this enough to conclude that the $v_i$ are lineary independent?

Assume $0=\sum\lambda_i v_i$. Get $$0=\left(\sum\lambda_i v_i,x\right)=\sum\lambda_i (v_i,x),$$ but $(v_i,x)>0$, hence there is a $\lambda_k\ge 0$ and a $\lambda_j\le 0$.

How could I continue?

Comment: just interested -- have you tried to pick a counterexample with your intuition? offhand looks like it could be more productive, not sure if the statement is true or not

Comment: Yes, but the statement should be true.

Comment: First note that you can assume $x$ is in the span of $v_1,\dots,v_m$ (take its orthogonal projection on the span).

Comment: Can you give details why I can assume that? If $x$ were not in the span, then...?